# How to sum arrayListOf items in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an arrayList of Long values and I want to sum them.

val arrayList: ArrayList<Any?> = arrayListOf() and list looks like below.

[image]

How to sum all of Long values? I tried adding like below but giving compilation issues. Please help me!

```
var size = 0L
for (key in arrayList.indices) {
size = size + arrayList[key]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided is correct when you have a proper `List<Long>` or `ArrayList<Long>`. You can also directly call the stdlib function `sum()` which does the same thing:

```kotlin
val list = listOf(1L, 2L, 3L)
println(list.sum())
```

However it looks like you are declaring an `ArrayList<Any?>` here, which prevents the compiler from knowing that the elements are `Long` values. You should declare it as a list of longs instead:

```kotlin
val arrayList: ArrayList<Long> = arrayListOf()
```

Note that we usually don't explicitly specify `ArrayList`, but prefer to use the more general interface `List` as a declared type. In the same mindset, you can use `listOf` instead of `arrayListOf` if you have  no particular reason to want an `ArrayList`.

```kotlin
val list = listOf<Long>()
```

Comment: by changing the ArrayList<Any?> to ArrayList<Long?> worked!! Thanks Man